# Apportioning two layers using mapbox studio classic

Tags: mapbox, apportion

I am using Mapbox Studio Classic to take two shapefiles--one with census tract geometries and the other with my own custom defined geometries. I want to apportion the two geometries so that I can get population data for my custom defined geometries. Is there anyway to do this using Mapbox? This is for a political science project and I don't have access to more robust programs like ESRI Arcgis.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this in Mapbox Studio, but you can certainly add your geometries to your census tract geometries in QGIS. QGIS is like ArgGIS but it is free software.